# Vowels and Consonants with Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove words from an input string that contain more vowels than consonants.
I wish to use a regular expression for this, can anyone give me any advice?

```
Input: eef geggughhht oaiu hjekloykj
Output: geggughhht hjekloykj
```

here's some my pseudo code

```java
String str = "eef geggughhht oaiu hjekloykj";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]+");

for (String ch : str.split(" ")) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ch);
    int countVowels = 0;
    int countConsonants = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ch.length(); i++) {
        if(matcher.find(i)){
            countVowels++;
        } else {
            countConsonants++;
        }
    }
    if (countVowels > countConsonants){
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this approach:

```
String str = "eef geggughhht oaiu hjekloykj";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); 

String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    String cstr = p.matcher(arr[i]).replaceAll("");
    if ( cstr.length() >= (arr[i].length() - cstr.length()) ) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
geggughhht
hjekloykj
```

Using this approach we remove all vowels in each word of the string and then compare remaining string's (com[rising all consonants) length with vowel's string.